# How to test format of data in a column - Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have recently started testing my python code with pytest.
I am trying to test that in the output file, a column should have value in certain format as a different format can break the code:

Example:
The value should be '5007_P2_274' and not '5007_274_P2'

I am trying this test :

```py
Val = '5007_274_P2'

try:
   Val == '5007_P2_274'

except ValueError as err:
   print(err)
```

But i am not sure if this will test the format the content of the column everytime. Like the values can be different but it would be something like:

5*_ P* _*

and not

5* _ * _P*

How should I approach it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like this as well. Chris has already given you a good solution.

```
import re

#using regEx, you can check for the pattern

check = re.compile(r'\d{4}_P\d_\d{3}') 

x = '5007_274_P2'
y = '5007_P2_274'

cx = check.search(x)==None #equating it to None results in 
cy = check.search(y)==None #True if matched else False

print ('cx :',x, 'is :', cx)
print ('cy :',y, 'is :', cy)
```

**Output will be:**

```
cx : 5007_274_P2 is : True
cy : 5007_P2_274 is : False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch):

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch

fnmatch('5007_274_P2', "5*_P*_*")
# False

fnmatch('5007_274_P2', "5*_*_P*")
# True
```